# Subtracting cells only if both have a value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to subtract two cells in excel but only if both cells have a value. More specifiaclly in my case the formula in cell **C2** is currently `=B2-A2` but I only want this to be calculated when **B2** has a value or **A2** has a value. I tried this formula

```
=IF(AND(B12<>"",A12<>""),B12-A12," ")
```

but after the 12th row, it started showing an error of `#VALUE!`

Comment: You may have non numeric or spaces somewhere down. Instead of checking for "" check for Number using ISNUMBER function e.g. =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),ISNUMBER(B1)),B1-A1,"")   Try this formula and check now.

Comment: @pat2015, Thank you. This formula works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ISBLANK` function:

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)),"",B2-A2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can resort to `ISNUMBER` to check if the fields have values that can be subtracted:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(A2), ISNUMBER(B2)), IF(ISNUMBER(B2), B2, 0) - IF(ISNUMBER(A2), A2, 0), "")
```